# Align logo + h2 in center of header with a responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have searched many threads here but could not find something more peculiar to my needs. I have a logo image 50x50px and h2 text element. I want to keep both elements side by side but in the absolute center of my header. I have tried various CSS techniques but cannot get it done. Below is simple bootstrap structure that I am trying to use:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"><img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature" alt="LOGO"> 
         <h2>FOUR SEASONS INTERNATIONAL (PVT) LTD</h2></div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: We can't help unless you provide your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use this css

```
img + h1{
  display: inline-block
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

remove positions whatever you added use only `margin,padding, top, left, right bottom` and  use `center` tag after `col-md-12` put both img and heading inside the center tag and also add `class col-sm-12`

Comment: Hi Narayan, this worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Narayan, Tell me how to accept answers. I tried to upvote your answer by clicking on up arrow and it shows "1" for a fraction of second and then becomes zero again. I think they accept votes from folks with better reputation. Mine is just 6. Poor fellow :(

Comment: see the down of down key u will get a right sign just click on that it will be green

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for **[display:flex with align-items:center](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)**

```css
.test{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 test"><img src="https://placeimg.com/50/50/nature" alt="LOGO"> 
         <h2>FOUR SEASONS INTERNATIONAL (PVT) LTD</h2></div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Spirit, Thanks for responding, however, your snippet is not keeping the header in absolute center. It is more on left from the center.